# python- CSV parsing issue- ignore the separator within the curly brackets

Tags: python, pandas

Facing an issue for parsing the following CSV file row:

```
UPDATED,464,**"{\"node-id\":\"\",\"change-type\":\"UPDATED\",\"object-type\":\"service\",\"internalgeneratedepoch\":1674472915591000,\"topic-name\":\"Service\",\"object-id\":\"wdm_tpdr_service1\",\"changed-attributes\":{\"lifecycle-state\":{\"old-value\":\" \",\"new-value\":\"planned\"},\"administrative-state\":{\"old-value\":\" \",\"new-value\":\"outOfService\"}},\"internaleventid\":464}"**,1674472915591000,,wdm_tpdr_service1,service
```

Issue is with the column 3 data (highlighted in bold) which has commas inside the curly braces and double quotes. I am not able to read this column data as a single data point, pandas is splitting this data across the commas which are read as separators. Can someone help please.

Want to read the following string as a single data point:

```
"{"node-id":"","change-type":"UPDATED","object-type":"service","internalgeneratedepoch":1674472915591000,"topic-name":"Service","object-id":"wdm_tpdr_service1","changed-attributes":{"lifecycle-state":{"old-value":" ","new-value":"planned"},"administrative-state":{"old-value":" ","new-value":"outOfService"}},"internaleventid":464}"
```

Tried this code:

```
csv_input = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=',(?![^{]*})',engine="python",index_col=False)
```

But its not working for all the rows.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided doesn't work because it contains an **invalid regex expression** as the delimiter which is not allowed. The regex expression is not valid because it is looking for a closing curly brace which may not be present in some of the rows in the comma separated file. To fix this, you can either remove the regex expression and use a simple comma as the delimiter or you can look for a more specific pattern within the string in the delimiter argument such as a certain set of characters or words.

You can try using the json library to parse the string that is in the third column:

```
import json

csv_input = pd.read_csv(file_name)

# read the third column in the csv
third_column = csv_input[2]

# parse the string as json
parsed_data = json.loads(third_column)

# use the parsed json data however you want

# If you want to store the parsed data in the csv, you can create a new column and add the results there.

csv_input['parsed_data'] = [json.loads(x) for x in third_column]
```

Comment: How can I read this full string, as its splitting the returned String across the delimiter?

"{"node-id":"","change-type":"UPDATED","object-type":"service","internalgeneratedepoch":1674472915591000,"topic-name":"Service","object-id":"wdm_tpdr_service1","changed-attributes":{"lifecycle-state":{"old-value":" ","new-value":"planned"},"administrative-state":{"old-value":" ","new-value":"outOfService"}},"internaleventid":464}"

How can I return the full line, as pandas csv.reader splits this string across the delimiter "," ?

Comment: You can use the pandas read_csv() function with the quotechar argument to read the whole string as one data point. 

csv_input = pd.read_csv(file_name, quotechar='"')

You can also use the quoting argument to specify how the read_csv() function should handle quote characters. For example, you can set quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL to tell the read_csv() function to always treat quote characters as part of the data.

csv_input = pd.read_csv(file_name, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)